# Kafka Consumer co-location. (Partition-Consumer allocation logic)

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-computing, apache-kafka-streams

The essence of distributed computation is to co-locate execution with data, or in other words, to send your code o your data, not your data to your code. That is the core design of Hadoop, Spark etc.

Does Kafka / Kafka Streams allow such setup? If yes, how? If no is there something planned, maybe as a subproject e.g. using Kubernetes or similar?

I know that we can define consumer groups for a topic but I don't understand how partitions are allocated to consuming application instances and if this allocation can be made to favour co-located instances.

Please let me know if there is a better term to search for as "kafka consumer co-location" didn't please the google gods :/

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka model is different. The Kafka cluster itself only stores data streams. Computation happens outside the Kafka cluster. Thus, there is only limited notion of co-location, ie, data will always be sent over the network to consumer/streams applications that do the processing.

For Kafka Streams, if you do joins for example, data sub-streams (based in Kafka partitions) of both input streams for the join will be co-located within a single Kafka Streams instance though to compute the correct result.

Note, that data stream processing is a different model and thus "shipping code to data" is not important as for batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

Why would we like to have that? 
**To minimize network traffic?** **Reduce delays?**

The wish is to *try* to give each partition to a local consumer, if possible. Any of the following condition makes that impossible or undesirable:

- Broker's host does not run any Consumers
- Local consumers don't subscribe to broker's topics
- Local consumer is overloaded, compared to some external consumers

Even in case of a relatively simple `StickyAssignor`, this problem turns out to be a multi-objective optimization:

- Optimize for evenly-distributed consumer load
- Optimize for preserving previously-assigned partitions

All, in the situation when topic distribution and consumer membership changes dynamically!

The next step would be to introduce some numerical measure of **locality**. Ideal assignment would try to connect broker and consumer on the same **host, rack, data center,** or **continent**. For example, you might wish to use ping time as a measure of distance between processes; or a number of hops.

Another dimension is variation of host capabilities and load. How many more partitions consumer's host can handle?

There must be a way to aggregate all the requirements into a single number: **how good is the assignment** of Topic X to a consumer Y.

In the end, you might get a `n * m` [matrix of assignment scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem): for each consumer-broker pair you might compute an assignment penalty. By [solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) that assignment problem in `O(n^3)` time you'll get the best possible assignment, which favors all aspects, important for your application:

- closeness to brocker
- closeness to end-user
- consumer's cache state
- CPU load and free disk space of consumer nodes
- maybe some other criteria like: regulation requirements, scheduled maintenance, cost of running a node

Kafka has a `PartitionAssignor` class, which controls relation between Topics and Consumers. Default is very simple algorithm, but there are more sophisticated implementations like [StickyAssignor](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html), which tries to preserve Consumer's caches. It is a [pluggable interface](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs), open for experimentation.

Kafka's philosophy favors robustness and universality. Maybe that's why such fragile and multi-faceted optimizations are not a part of a standard distribution.